# MVC2 Checkboxes: Still having problems; Or: What does isSelected got to do with it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

In the ever increasingly epic failure that are my Create and Edit forms, I'm still having problems generating checkboxes via Html.Checkbox().  I'm not sure if I should just manually write the HTML at this point.

I have a view model:

```
public class AdminGameReviewViewModel
{
    public Game GameData { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> AllGenres { get; set; }
    public List<PlatformListing> AllPlatforms { get; set; }
}
```

And a helper model:

```
public class PlatformListing
{
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And, I'm trying to generate the checkboxes like so:

```
<%: Html.Label("Platforms") %><br />
<% Model.AllPlatforms.ForEach(p => Html.Encode(Html.CheckBox("PlatformIDs", p.IsSelected, new { value = p.Platform.PlatformID }))); %>
```

But, they're not displaying at all.

I'm curious as to why I need to supply a boolean for the checkboxes themselves.  I'd think it would simply send back checked values, as an array or list similar to PHP's $_POST.  So, I'm not sure if I'm implementing my boolean property correctly, in addition to whatever other brain dead errors I'm committing.  The boolean is forcing me to bury the data I want to display/bind further than I'd like, and it's giving me problems 'seeing' what I'm doing wrong.

I keep getting the feeling I'm looking too deeply at my problem, and trying to make the solution more complicated than it should be.  Given my inexperience with MVC2/C#, I'm just not sure where to go from here.  It doesn't help that this seems to be the one part of form handling that's either glossed over or completely ignored by most demos and tutorials.

So, again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not writing anything to the Response stream.

Html.Checkbox() returns a string, it doesn't write directly to the response object (nor does Html.Encode() - that just escapes reserved characters and returns the result string). On top of all that, the ForEach extension method only executes an action, it doesn't return a value.

So you have to ditch the ForEach extension, and use the <%= %> or <%: %> code nuggets:

```
<% foreach (var p in Model.AllPlatforms) { %>
   <%= Html.CheckBox("PlatformIDs", p.IsSelected, new { value = p.Platform.PlatformID }) %>
<% } %>
```